# How to hide hover-effects on a website which occure while scrolling on elements on a mobile device?

Tags: javascript, html, css

on my website I got a navigation with many elements. The navigation is scrollable and if you hover over an element, it gets highlighted.

The Problem: If I visit my website with my iPad, while scrolling in the navigation, the element I drag on shows its hover-effect and gets highlighted. I don't want this to happen, whats a good solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't/how to make this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary** to reproduce it **in the question itself**. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I have not try this yet but you can consider this:

Add an on-scroll function to `<body>`, in the function, set the color of all elements in navigation list to normal color(the color when not hovered at), so that when you scroll the page on your Ipad, even you drag the element it will still not highlighted.

```
<body onscroll="scroll_function()">

<script>
function scroll_function(){
document.getElementByClassName("element_name").style.backgroundColor = ... (your normal color)
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Working without your code (always good to include that in a question btw), I'm gathering that the hover effect will be entirely CSS in spite of the javascript tag in the question, if that is the case you can use [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) to resolve this by simply creating a profile for devices you don't want the hover effect to happen on.

WRT the somewhat troublesome larger resolutions on modern handhelds, [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) is a quite extensive list of media query resolutions for differing handheld devices which should be helpful if you were to go down the route of attempting an MQ solution.

Comment: They ask how to avoid when scrolling, not on a certain device type, and neither can be solved with media query's.

Comment: I'm not sure it can't. This navigation problem occurs on certain devices (mobile ones) so the idea of removing the hover effect from them makes sense in that regard.

Answer (score -1):

Create an CSS media query that will use custom css on devices smaller or a larger screen than x pixels

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    some-element:hover{
       text-decoration:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't distinguish an iPad from a PC using pixel detection

Answer (score -1):

Hover effects are pointless on mobile devices and tablets because you do not use a mouse to hover over elements.

Use all you hover effects as such:

```html
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    /* STYLES HERE */
}
```

If you still use the hover effects on all media queries, when you click on elements, the hover effect will take place.

Comment: You can't distinguish an iPad from a PC using pixel detection

Comment: With e.g. media query's and responsive CSS tech. like Flexbox, CSS Grid, etc. Still, how is your answer gonna work for e.g. an iPad, where its `min-width` is equal (and sometime larger) than a standard desktop screen?

Comment: iPad in portrait & landscapeand (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}

Comment: Same goes for portrait view. Check window resize for Ipad Pro and Ipad that is build-in in chrome.

Comment: Also you can add -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2; so don't worry about resolutions over 2k

Comment: FYI, the `*-device-width/height` is taken out of the standards.